# jenkins kills ssh session when supervisord restarts

Tags: jenkins, ssh, supervisord

I'm using jenkins to do a few actions in a remote server.
I have an Execute Shell command in which I do the following:

```
sudo ssh <remote server> 'sudo service supervisor restart'
sleep 30
```

When jenkins reaches the first line I can see 'Restarting Supervisor' but after a moment I see that jenkins closed the ssh connection and moved on to the second line.
I tried adding a 'sleep 30' after the restart command but it still doesn't work.
Seems jenkins doesn't wait for the supervisor restart command to be completed.
Problem is it's not something that always happens, just sometimes, but it does make a lot of problems when it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can never be certain all processes started by supervisord are in a 'ready' state after a restart. Even is the restart action would wait for processes to be started, it wouldn't know if they are 'ready'.

In docker-compose setups that need to know if a certain service is available I've used an extra 'really ready' check for this - optionally in a loop with a sleep/wait. If the process that you are starting opens a port you can use one of the variations of '[wait-for](https://github.com/eficode/wait-for)' for this.